# Is meta tag [qgis] needed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Another question intended for Main was just asked here on Meta:

[Saving Geo-Tif from QGIS creates black TIF?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4685/saving-geo-tif-from-qgis-creates-black-tif)

I suspect part of the reason askers of such questions think they have found the right place is because it accepts a meta tag of [qgis](/questions/tagged/qgis) and they think that it is a normal tag.

Is there any reason why we need a [qgis](/questions/tagged/qgis) meta tag here on Meta, or should it be burninated?

There are no tags for other GIS software products and companies.  I recall that there were a few at some time in the past but I think they were burninated long ago.

Please note that this question is about the [qgis](/questions/tagged/qgis) meta tag here on Meta, and has nothing to do with the [qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/qgis) tag on Main.

Comment: The [meta-tag:qgis] has now been burninated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am a relatively inexperienced user but I tend to agree that it should be *burninated*.

I can't think of a scenario where a `qgis` tag would be needed on GIS Meta, and having looked through the other tags it is clearly out of place, and doesn't fit. The only other software related tag is `Firefox` with a specific tag wiki explaining that it is to do with problems using Stackexchange with that browser, so that is valid. The same context could not be applied to `qgis`.

So in my mind it is clear, I say burninate it.

Comment: I think that you are right on both counts i.e. keep [meta-tag:firefox] because it is used by the software that powers GIS Stack Exchange; and burninate [meta-tag:qgis] because it is not used by the software that powers GIS Stack Exchange.

Comment: Agreed with both points